# C error: expression must have a constant value (windows code example)

Tags: c, winapi

I have been trying to compile the code "Edit control"

from here:  http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/controls/

now my compiler (VS2013) wont let me compile this code while giving me that error: Error    574 error C2057: expected constant expression

code part:

```
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED) {

            int len = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwndEdit) + 1;
            wchar_t text[len];

            GetWindowTextW(hwndEdit, text, len);
            SetWindowTextW(hwnd, text);
        }
```

edit:

i have used this code to fix the problem:

```
wchar_t *text = calloc(len, sizeof(wchar_t));
if (text != NULL)
{
    // STUFF
}
free(text);
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: Added the code part

Comment: than how can i fix it?

Comment: @Thebaron At which line _exactly_ do you get thbe error ?

Answer (score 4):

While C99 support [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) Microsoft doesn't support them.

That means that

```
wchar_t text[len];
```

is not valid with Visual Studio 2013 c compiler.

You can use [malloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) to do so:

```
wchar_t *text = malloc(sizeof(wchar_t)*len);
if (text != NULL)
{
    // STUFF
}
free(text);
```

**EDIT**

Take note that `malloc`ated memory is not initialized, as with VLAs that are stack allocated, so memory must be inited if needed using:

```
memset(text, 0, sizeof(whar_t)*len);
```

or using [calloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) instead of malloc:

```
wchar_t *text = calloc(len, sizeof(wchar_t));
if (text != NULL)
{
    // STUFF
}
free(text);
```

Comment: funny how they don't support VLA in C99 which mandates VLA support, and they do support it in C++ which forbids it

Comment: @M.M `while(Microsoft == !StandardC)` is and infinite loop... ;)

Comment: @M.M Was an implementation opting out of VLA support by defining `__STDC_NO_VLA__` not added until later than C99 ? Genuinely curious, as I don't know when it became optional, and whether MS actually defines that macro where they don't support it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Became optional in C11 (probably due to MS lobbying of the standards committee)

Comment: @WhozCraig [For reference](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.std.c/2012-08/msg00105.html)

Comment: hmm i tried your solution but now when i check text it contain only one char

Comment: @Thebaron I'm not getting you. How do you check it and at what point of your code?

Comment: http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/controls/   check Edit control

Comment: Ok, but for example, if you check the value with Visual Studio variable debugger after it's allocation you can see garbage, due to the memory content. It is visualized as string and it stop showing value at the first 0 found into your "array".

Comment: well than im pretty lost :/ im trying to make a gui for my program and it get messy... could you help me?

Comment: You should isolate you problems and post different questions for each one. SO people will give you a hand, surely.

Comment: In C99, VLAs were mandatory; C11 relaxed it to make VLAs optional. However, Microsoft's C compiler supports only C89/C90. VLAs were not introduced until C99, which Microsoft does not support and have not ever promised to support. I doubt Microsoft did any lobbying of the C standards committee. They are only concerned with C++. The only C99 features they are supporting are those that are also required by C++ language specifications, and those are only supported by the C++ compiler (not the C compiler).